# How to resolve a Promise after a for loop that implements another Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, pdf.js

I'm using Mozilla's [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) module in a `Promise` in order to get every PDF page transformed into a JPG image. My code creates the file images with the help of the `fs` module, and it is used as a `Promise` with the `promisify` function on the `utils` module. At this point the code works perfectly, but I had place a `Resolve` function after, and it is not being fired, and the `Promise` is hanging. Where should I put the resolve?

I've tried at the end of the function, but I'm affraid that the way I'm handling the `Promise` is not completely executed, and I'm being stoock because the implementation of the `Promise` that I had to do in order to get the **PDF.js** module working

```
const CanvasFactory = require('./../../lib/canvas/canvas');
const pdfjsLib = require('./../../lib/pdf.js/node_modules/pdfjs-dist');

const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const convertPDF2PNG = (pdfFilePath) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfFilePath);
  loadingTask.promise.then((pdf) => {
    const maxPages = pdf.numPages;
    const convertPDFPromises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= maxPages; i += 1) {
      const page = pdf.getPage(i);
      convertPDFPromises.push(page.then(page => {
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.0 });
        const canvasFactory = new CanvasFactory();
        const canvasAndContext = canvasFactory.create(viewport.width, viewport.height);
        const renderContext = {
          canvasContext: canvasAndContext.context,
          viewport,
          canvasFactory,
        };
        const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(() => {
          const image = canvasAndContext.canvas.toBuffer();
          writeFile(`temporal/output${i}.jpg`, image)
            .then(() => {
              // TODO: add query to insert images in Database
              console.log(`File ${i} added`);
            })
            .catch(writeErr => {
              console.error(writeErr)
              reject(writeErr);
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
          }); 
      }));
    }
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    console.error(reason);
    reject(reason);
  });
  resolve();
});
```

This is the responses I get on the console

```
File 2 added
File 3 added
File 1 added
```

I want to know why the `Promise` is not being resolved.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! To deal with the loop, use `Promise.all`.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Heres an example of three simultaneous promises being cast and returned in an imperative manner.
`let [targetsDaily, targetsMonthly, targetsYearly] = await Promise.all([
        this.downloadTargets(map.daily),
        this.downloadTargets(map.monthly),
        this.downloadTargets(map.yearly)
      ])`

Comment: Ok, so the anti-pattern is the for loop? not the `const convertPDF2PNG = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}))` itself?